# Javascript shift() unshift() mnemonics?

Tags: javascript, terminology, history

I am having hard time remembering what `Array.shift()` and `Array.unshift()` do.

After few years, I still have too check out reference from time to time when I need to use one of them. Can anyone explain **why** those names are choosen and how to memorize which one does what?

I have no such problem with `Array.push()` and `Array.pop()`

Comment: Easy to remember if you mentally drop the "f" in shift / unshift: `shift` _removes_ elements and `unshift` _adds_ them :)

Comment: @VickyChijwani I would accept it as an answer

Comment: @VickyChijwani I would flag your comment as hilarious :D

Comment: Without a doubt @VickyChijwani comment is the best answer to the question of how to remember what they do

Comment: Just remember the "Shift" is shorter than "Unshift", "Shift" is also going to make the Array shorter as well.

I think the problem with remembering is not whether it adds from front or back, its which adds/removes from the front

Comment: The easiest way to remember the difference: The longer words (push, unshift) make the array longer, the shorter words (pop, shift) make it shorter.

Comment: When you `shift` a car into 2nd gear you're making 2nd the new `0` for your engine to idle at. Unshifting (or downshifting) magically creates new gear ratios. Just think... when you're driving you can never shift down... once you shift... you lose that 1st gear forever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is certainly the most confusing pair of function names. The only salvation I can offer is to remember one of the following two things:

- Shift can be thought of as "moving something around," and perhaps you can picture that if you "shift" an array around a bunch, something is liable to fall off the end (or in this case, the beginning). Unshift puts things back the way they were.
- It's the opposite of what it sounds like it should be. `unshift` sounds like undoing something, but in fact, it's putting something onto the array.

Good luck!

Answer (score 22):

As I known.

The shift command is come from the binary bit shift [1]. for Example.

```
    001100
0 < 011000 // when you shift left
|
Yay!
```

I think it is quite simple it is just like you push it from behind. So this makes sense for me.

The unshift is the opposite way of shift.

```
    001100
1 > 001100 // they called it unshift
    1001100
    |
    Yay!
```

So that's it, Hope this helps!

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts

Comment: So that is the problem! Because I can think as shift:  001100 < 1 = 0011001, and unshift: 001100 -> = 00110 + 0. So the question is how to  memorize the direction? Push/pop are easy, push goes in, pop goes out.

Comment: @Chokchai—Not a good analogy. Shift removes the first member of the array and returns it, unshift adds the supplied arguments to the start of an array in the order they are presented and returns the new length of the array.

Comment: @exebook—there is no simple way to remember it, just remember where to find it in the spec and look it up if in doubt.

Comment: This is a great explanation. Personally I prefer enqueue and dequeue.

Comment: @RobG It's not an analogy, it's where the name actually comes from (OP asked _Can anyone explain why those names are choosen_)

Answer (score 9):

`a.push(e)` *pushes* `e` onto the **end** of `a`.

`e = a.pop()` *pops* the **last** element from `a`, to `e`.

`a.unshift(e)` *enqueues* `e` to the **start** of `a`.

`e = a.shift()` *gets* the **first** element from `a` to `e`.

Use `push` and `pop` for stacks.

Use `unshift` and `pop` for queues. (Or `push` and `shift`)

I remember the difference between `shift` (destructive) and `unshift` (constructive) simply by remembering that I use **un**-shift for **en**-queueing, and `shift` is the opposite to `unshift`.

Comment: Yes, I know what they do... But tomorrow I will forget which one does what. I tried many times!

Comment: @exebook Apologies, see edit.

Answer (score 9):

Just think of your keyboard:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> ***gets*** a capital version of the ***first*** key you press.

`.shift()` ***gets*** the ***first*** item off the array.

Comment: This is simple enough for me.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

> SHIFTer makes a drifter

It returns the first entry to the variable.

and -

> UNSHIFTer is a weenier that sneaks in line

Inserts argument as first entry in array

Oh, there are deep psychological techniques at work here!! :-o But seriously, you will remember it for its peculiarity :-)

Comment: Of all of the answers I actually like this best. Push/Pop are easy, and I can just remember "shifter makes a drifter" since it leaves you with something drifting out of the array.